# Expression where someone is promoting a value they do not actually have in order to have better public relations

Tags: single-word-requests

I tagged the question as "single-word request", but I am pretty sure it is an expression of two words. One of those words is the word "value" accompanied with another word that I am looking for.

It would be used under this context:

"The company wants us to take a picture of all the employees for Earth day, they are just value __________ to get better public relations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the word "signaling"? See this Wikipedia article about virtue signaling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtue_signalling (I spell "signaling" with one L  as an American, but "signalling" would have two Ls if you are from a Commonwealth country).

Comment: Yes! That is what I was looking for! I wrongly had the word value stuck in my head!

Comment: Yes, "virtue signal(l)ing" is the expression, though I could understand thinking thinking of "value", since it sounds similar and has a similar meaning to "virtue"!